# PostgreSQL - Use a function to name a column in a select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to set the name of a column in a 'select .. from' query dinamically. So I created a function to return the name of the column and tried to use it in a select query.

The function is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_column_name(iddoc int, campo text) RETURNS text
AS $$
#print_strict_params on
DECLARE
campoid text;
BEGIN

    SELECT campo_id INTO STRICT campoid
    FROM campos_td c
    JOIN (SELECT field4, field3 
        FROM frm7 
        WHERE iddocumento = iddoc) f ON c.tema_id = f.field3

    RETURN 'field10' || campoid;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I've tried things like:

```
SELECT get_column_name(2, 'Size') FROM frm7
SELECT f.get_column_name(2, 'Size') FROM frm7 as f
```

But none of them works.

Comment: Clever, but SQL doesn't work like that.  A function cannot return an identifier.  Columns need to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pgsql `EXECUTE` [command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-statements.html) lets you run an arbitrary SQL string, in particular, one you have built up with column names passed in at runtime.

Comment: I tried the following:
PREPARE query (text) AS SELECT $1 FROM frm7 f
EXECUTE query1 (get_column(2, 'Asunto')). But the result is a select of some text not a select of a column so the result is not the expected.

Comment: This is a different use of `EXECUTE`. You want the `EXECUTE` _inside_ a PGSQL stored procedure. (See link in answer.) Your eventual result will be something like `SELECT * FROM my_stored_procedure('column_foo');`. Whether you do this as a prepared statement or just a raw SQL query is up to you and probably not important.

Answer (score -1):

I am not well versed in sql but you may try this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

set @query = 'SELECT ' + get_column_name(2, 'Size') + ' FROM frm7';

execute @query;
```

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'col1'; 
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colName + ' FROM frm7';

execute @query;
```